# Can I create a Bluetooth RFCOMM connection in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, rfcomm

I know that in Win8.1 an explicit RFCOMM Api exist. Nevertheless I wonder whether I can create a direct RFCOMM connection also from Win7 and which API I must use. Currently I simply use SPP, which is basically 95% RFCOMM, but it directly integrates as COM port in the system when pairing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://SimpleBluetooth4Win.Sourceforge.net

It's a small library that could help you.

This library works under windows 7 and compiles with the Visual Studio 2008 SP1 if you:

- link against the ws2_32.lib library
- change the std::tuple with the std::tr1::tuple and the std::get with the std::tr1::get
- choose "Not Set" as the project "Character Set"

The libray uses the windows bluetooth networking API

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

and works perfectly if your bluetooth USB dongle or bluetooth device has been correctly recognized by the appropriate drivers and the remote bluetooth device is already paired with the PC.

Comment: Hi Amos, sounds very interesting, I'll check later. Thanks!